# Where am I supposed to go at the beginning of the game?

Tags: half-life

I am having problems playing Half Life (Part 1). I mean that since I entered the Black Mesa Research Facility, I go on roaming around here and there. I can see only scientists and few securities. But what do I actually need to do there?

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the suit. If you've been going around the map then you've probably seen the locker room. There is the suit, you need to press the button on the console, which will open the suit compartment. Then you need to walk over it to actually put it on (Tip: while you are here, press E on the lockers, one or two of them open and give you some armor).

[image]

6:30 on-wards

Then you need to make your way to the elevator and go downstairs and etc.

Comment: But where are those suits or elevators ??
I mean if you can send some scrren-shots please..

Comment: @RahulRoy Check out the video, watch it from 6:30 on-wards

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the color-coded guidelines on the wall: Green leads to "Personnel Facilities", which is where the suit can be found.

Comment: Easy there, @RahulRoy :)  You are playing the greatest game of ALL TIME!!  Patience is a virtue.  Talk to the scientists; talk to Barney.  The game has some puzzles but is linear.  Once you get immersed into the Gorden's world, you will love it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friends.. I think I have got my problem solved. Well it would be nice if anyone can tell whether there is any option to save the game in between ??

Comment: From the lobby with the guard, there should be colored lines that lead down the hall.  Try following each one to their destinations.

Comment: Where is the warzone or main fighting area ??